# Bootstrap 4 menus with 3 levels - first sub-menu won't hold to select from

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using BS 4 and jQuery 2.2.4.  I have created a navbar with 3 layers of menus (i.e. 2 levels of drop-down from the top-most level).

The menu works great except one glitch when on mobile.  On mobile, the menu collapses to the hamburger just fine.  I can click it down to reveal the menu/subs.

The issue comes when I touch the sub-menu (or mouse-over on small pc browser window)... it reveals its sub, but then as I move the mouse down to choose an item, the drop-down goes back up on that level only, hence cannot choose anything under that sub.  On the actual mobile device where there's no mouse, I touch the sub-items, but nothing happens.

Here's the thing... this only happens on the 1st sub-menu's items (Smart Phone).  It doesn't happen on the 2nd sub-menus items (Computer).

It seems to be happening on the 1st sub-menu's items whether it's the Smart Phone or Computer menu (I tried swapping the code order).  I even duplicated (with unique IDs of course) the 1st sub-menu multiple times; the result was all of them had same behavior - except very last sub-menu (which when there are just the Smart Phone and Computer subs, then Computer becomes the "last"), so perhaps that offers a clue.

I made a video to better illustrate my late-night wording (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X_3kY-PBEgLra_mhvpZwPRsQMxd2-SRD).

My guess is this is an easy fix for the trained eye.  Would appreciate learning the error of my ways :)

Now for the code...

1. CSS

```
    /*=========================== Navigation ============================ */

    .navbar {
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.21);
    }

    .navbar-nav a {
        font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 16.5px;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
        line-height: 25px;
    }

    .navbar-nav a {
        color: #404044;
    }

    .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        padding-right: 1.2rem !important;
        padding-left: 1.2rem !important;
    }

    .nav-item {
        border-radius: 0px;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }

    .navbar .nav-item:focus .dropdown.show {
        background: transparent !important;
    }

    .navbar .nav-item.active,
    .navbar .nav-item:hover {
        transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }

    .navbar .nav-item.active {
        border-bottom: 6px solid;
    }

        .navbar .nav-item.active a .dropdown-item {
            border: 0px !important;
        }

    .navbar .nav-item:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }


    /* dropdown style */

    .nav-link.dropdown-toggle:focus {
        background: transparent !important;
    }

    .dropdown-item {
        color: #fff !important;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        line-height: 45px !important;
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
        box-shadow: 1px -1px 10px 4px rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.21);
        border: 0px;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    .navbar .dropdown-menu a:before {
        display: none;
    }


    /* navbar brand */

    .nav-brand {
        line-height: 20px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

        .nav-brand img {
            max-height: 60px;
        }

    .navbar-brand i {
        vertical-align: sub;
        margin-right: 10px;
        font-size: 45px;
    }

    .navbar-toggler {
        transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
        background: #fff;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }


    /*
    *
    * ==========================================
    * CUSTOM UTIL CLASSES - responsible for the 3rd level of sub-menu (e.g. MAIN / SUB-MENU / ITEM1, ITEM 2)
    * ==========================================
    *
    */
    .navbar-nav li:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu {
        position: relative;
    }

        .dropdown-submenu > a:before {  /* changed from "after" to "before", else the misalignment as described below occurred */
        content: "\f0da";  /* doesn't seem to do anything with "before" modification above */
        /*float: right; - this causes sub-menu caret icons to misalign to below the sub's title/name */
        border: none;
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        }

        .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        }
```

2. HTML

```
    <div id="navbarContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a id="dropdownMenu1" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" 
            aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">Products
            </a>
            <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/phonecase">Phone Case</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a id="dropdownMenu2" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" 
                aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">Smart Phone
                </a>
                <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="/smartphone/iphone">iPhone</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="/smartphone/android">Android</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a id="dropdownMenu3" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" 
                aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">Computer
                </a>
                <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3" class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="/computer/mac">iMac</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="/computer/pc">PC</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a id="dropdownMenu4" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" 
            aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">Shoes
            </a>
            <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu4" class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/shoes/loafers">Loafers</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/shoes/sandals">Sandals</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/other1">Other 1</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/other2">Other 2</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/other3">Other 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

After much trial & error, I am pleased to report I found the answer!  Eureka!

It was one simple change on one line in the CSS:

this...

```
    .navbar-nav li:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }
```

to...

```
    .navbar-nav li:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display:grid;  /* changing "block" to "grid" got everything working (except for IE11, but I'll report that elsewhere)
    }
```